# Redirect Javascript (Jquery) function to homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect the following JS snippet, to `http://localhost/homepage` at the end of `$('form').submit();` How can I do it ?

```
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myModal .btn.btn-primary').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('form').submit();
      });
    });
  //]]>
</script>
```

the html involved is here :

```
<div class='modal' id='myModal'>
  <div class='modal-header'>
    <div class='close'><a href="/">x</a></div>
    <h3>Add Tags</h3>

  </div>
  <div class='modal-body'>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tagging" data-remote="true" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="7x2CSQ5spL32f1rjCJd5MdwYO6uZ+IwVsLEQ9ZB/Xcc=" /></div>
        <input id="tags_string" name="tags_string" type="text" value="zoz" />
        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="4f1c95e51d41c80ff20003f0" />
        <div class='modal-footer'>
          <!-- .btn.btn-primary= submit_tag "Add tag" -->
          <a class='btn btn-primary'>
            <input class='hidden' name='commit' type='submit' value='Add Tag'>

          </a>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't find that ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you submit the form, it stops processing, it goes to the page where the form's 'action' directs (in your example, whatever page runs at /tagging) and that's it. If you want to do any redirection it'll have to do in the /tagging page after it does whatever it needs to do with the form fields